# Texas Instruments Step-Down DC-DC Converter orientation

Tags: pcb, ldo, footprint

I have a Step Down DC-DC Converter IC, purchased from Texas Instruments.

Part number: TPS54331

Datasheet: [www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps54331.pdf?ts=1599690098737&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps54331.pdf?ts=1599690098737&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)

IRL Image:

[image]

PCB Footprint -

[image]

Does the line signify the pin 1 ident?

All my other components have an ident. I am sure this information would be somewhere but I just don't know the words to use. Thanks!

Comment: There is a chamfer in one of the upper edges of the IC. You can see this in the datasheet mechanical drawing (page 33). According to the datasheet, pin 1 is along the edge with the chamfer. What Tony M says may also be true. But I have always relied on the chamfer.

Comment: Hey cheers for that, it's always good to have more information, especially if the text is faded or non-existent. Thanks.

Comment: Ditto, the chamfer gives you pin 1, also (usually) if you rotate the part so you can read the writing, pin1 will be on the bottom left. If you get the part on tape and reel, pin1 is usually nearest sprocket holes,

Answer (score 4):

With the IC viewed with its marked text upright (reading left to right)...

Pin 1 is the bottom-left pin. This is standard for a DIL IC package.

The upright line to the left of the text is running between pin 1 (bottom-left) and pin 8 (top-left).

Comment: My man! Thanks for the prompt comment and the edits too!